# Help to solve a system equation: $x-y+xy=-4$; $xy(x-y)=-21$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

I need to solve a system equation. Here's how it looks:

$x-y+xy=-4$

$xy(x-y)=-21$

I tried to substitute $x-y$ with $w$ and $xy$ with $t$ to simplify everything. After that I got this system equation:

$w+t=-4$

$tw=-21$

I solved this new system equation and got these results:

$t_1=-7, w_1=3$

$t_2=3, w_2=-7$

After all these steps I ended up with 2 new system equations:

1.

$xy=-7 (\leftarrow t)$

$x-y=3 (\leftarrow w)$

2.

$xy=3 (\leftarrow t)$

$x-y=-7 (\leftarrow w)$

Looks like the first one doesn't have any solutions. And I can't solve the second one. Am I doing wrong steps? Please help me to solve this system equation. Thanks.

Comment: Your first equation says $(x-1)y=-4-x$, so $y=(4+x)/(1-x)$. Putting this into the second equation will give an equation for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
x-y+xy&=-4
,\\
xy(x-y)&=-21
.
\end{align}

We can consider $u,v$

\begin{align} 
u&=x-y
,\\
v&=xy
\end{align}
as two roots of the quadratic equation,

\begin{align}
z^2+az+b&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
a&=-(u+v)=-(x-y+xy)=4
,\\
b&=uv=xy(x-y)=-21
,
\end{align}

so \eqref{1} is

\begin{align}
z^2+4z-21&=0
\end{align}

which has two real solutions

\begin{align}
z_{1,2}&=3,-7
.
\end{align}

Since we can not distinguish 
which of the two is $u$ and which is $v$,
we need to consider both cases:

\begin{align}
\text{Case 1.}\quad
&
\begin{cases}
u&=x-y=3
,\\
v&=xy=-7
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
\text{Case 2.}\quad
&
\begin{cases}
u&=x-y=-7
,\\
v&=xy=3
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

We can exploit the quadratic equation again (twice),
considering two roots, $x$ and $-y$,
since we can get the values of the sum and product of named roots
as

\begin{align}
\text{case 1.}\quad
&
\begin{cases}
x+(-y)=3
,\\
x(-y)=-xy=7
,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\text{case 2.}\quad
&
\begin{cases}
x+(-y)=-7
,\\
x(-y)=-xy=-3
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The two quadratic equations are then

\begin{align}
\text{case 1:}\quad
t^2-3t+7&=0
,\\
\text{case 2:}\quad
t^2+7t-3&=0
.
\end{align}

The first case does not have real roots,
but the second one provides two real roots,

\begin{align}
t_{1,2}&=
-\tfrac72\pm\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
.
\end{align}

And as before, we have to consider two options,
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x&=-\tfrac72+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
,\\
y&=-(-\tfrac72-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61})
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x&=-\tfrac72-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
,\\
y&=-(-\tfrac72+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61})
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The final substitution into original pair of equations
confirms that the two solutions are indeed

\begin{align}
 \begin{cases}
  x&=-\tfrac72+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
  \\
  y&=\phantom{-}\tfrac72+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
 \end{cases}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
 \begin{cases}
  x&=-\tfrac72-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
  ,\\
  y&=\phantom{-}\tfrac72-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{61}
  .
 \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! The best answer!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is linear in $y$; we have
$$
y(x-1)+x+4=0.
$$
Since $x=1$ is imposssible here, we can write $y=\frac{x+4}{1-x}$ and substitute this into the second equation. Then one obtains
$$
(x^2 + 7x - 3)(x^2 - 3x + 7)=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

We have the equations $$x-y+xy=-4\implies x-y=-4-xy\tag{1}$$ and $$xy(x-y)=-21\tag{2}$$ so substituting $(1)$ into $(2)$, we get $$xy(-4-xy)=-21\implies(xy)^2+4xy-21=0$$ Let $u=xy$. Then $$u^2+4u-21=0$$ and so...

Comment: I've ended up with the same 2 system equations like in my question. I don't know how to solve them... It seems like the first one doesn't have any solution, but I don't know how to solve the second one...

Comment: Note that we get $u=-7,3$. For the first one, we have $xy=-7$ so putting this into $(1)$, $$x-y=-4+7=3\implies x=3+y$$ Now put this back into $xy=(3+y)y=-7$ and solve!

Comment: _xy = (3 + y)y = −7_ doesn't have solutions --> _y^2 + 3y + 7 = 0_. But when I used _u = 3_, I got this equation _xy = (y - 7)y = 3_ --> _y^2 - 7y - 3 = 0_ and it has solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)